# AngularJS AJAX intercepted? Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'apply' of null

Tags: ajax, angularjs

I am having a hard time getting an AJAX call to work with AngularJS. I have to admin, I am a complete newb with AngularJS.

This is the full code:
https://gist.github.com/hendricius/93a646b031d23dba6847#file-angular_pages-js-coffee-L81

The error message: `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'apply' of null`

It seems like the AJAX events are intercepted or something.

Help appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Don't ever use jquery's ajax along with angularjs. It makes it hard to test. A more convenient way is the `$http` module from angular https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$http.

So your example would look something like this (I assume you are posting, not tested and not fluent in CoffeeScript ;)):

```
$http.post("/adwords_tools/keyword_estimates", _.map(keywords, (kw)-> kw.name)).success (response) ->
  console.log response
```

Comment: Accepted this as it's a good best practice.

The actual problem is within the `rack-mini-profiler` gem I was using for Rails. See this issue: https://github.com/MiniProfiler/ui/pull/13/commits